# How to fill FAB with image programmatically and fix LinearLayout cropping FAB shadow?

Tags: android-studio, bitmap, floating-action-button

I have a `LinearLayout` with FAB inside and the FAB is used as a button in which you click and it lets you choose an image as icon for group(like in Telegram and WhatsApp), and I have 2 problems:

1. I want to fill the FAB with the image the user has chosen(programmatically of course.)
2. The `LinearLayout` crops the FAB shadow and makes it look pixelated.
   And I have a question, is it even the right way to do it? using FAB? I've tried using CircleImageView but I have problems setting the default icon...
   Thank you very much in advance for any kind of help:)

I've tried to change it to CircleImageView but then I have problems of setting the default icon of choosing photo, and I've understood that round buttons should be FABs...
And I've tried changing it to `RelativeLayout` but the same problem happened...

XML:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/photo_title_bar_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_a_icon_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/add_image_background"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_blue"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@null" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/group_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:hint="Title"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Program:

```
        pickPhotoFAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddEditGroupActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //request the permission
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddEditGroupActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                        // result of the request.
                }
                if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddEditGroupActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    Intent photoPick = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(photoPick, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    Bitmap pictureBM = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

                    pickPhotoFAB.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), pictureBM));
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't get photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Actual result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hrdP.jpg,
When I choose an image the FAB just stays the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that FloatingActionButtons belong in the corner of the screen and only there.

Comment: [Official guidelines for using FABs](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/). I leave it to your consideration to use a FAB there.